# PHP - random with current keys

Tags: php, random

If I have this code:

```
array(0 => "hey", 1 => "bla", 2 => "test", 3 => "ag")
```

And I want to rand it, but with the current keys:

```
array(2 => "test", 0 => "hey", 3 => "ag", 1 => "bla");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm confused, after randomizing this, `array[2]` will still be `"test"`...

Comment: It's not you, really, it's PHP.

Comment: @Justin Ethier, it's true array[2] will still be "test" but the order that a foreach loop will iterate through the elements changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function you can use if you want:

```
function pkey_shuffle($arr){
    $keys = array_keys($arr); 
    shuffle($keys); 
    $new = array();
    $count = count($keys);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $new[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
    }
    return $new;
}

$arr = array(2 => "test", 0 => "hey", 3 => "ag", 1 => "bla");
print_r($arr);
echo '<br />';
print_r(pkey_shuffle($arr));
```